# how to instantiate a spring bean using a classloader?

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control

I have a specific requirement that i should be dynamically (at runtime) able to load and unload bean classes in my Spring IoC container.

A bean needs to be

1. created
2. destroyed
3. created again (from the same class, probable a new version of the same class)

the problem i am facing is that since the class in step 1 is loaded in system classloader, it remains there even when i destroy the bean. So in the step 3 i get an object of the old class, not the new class.

So the solution to my problem is to load the class in MyClassLoader instead of system classloader.

So my steps become

1. create the specific classloader
2. create the bean using specific class loader
3. set the bean reference to null and remove bean from AppContext
4. set the classloader reference to null

reload the bean using step 1 and 2

My Question is how to implement the above approach in Spring IoC container?

Thanks,

Regards,

Vimal

Comment: Can you just recreate spring context with a new classloader? Keep in mind recreating bean won't reinject it into existing beans wherever it was referred to. Also remember parent classloader always takes precedence over descendants.

Comment: @mrembisz hi, seems like a good idea to create AppContext itself in a new classloader. i shall give it a try. But will creating a AppContext in a new classloader will ensure all beans in this context also to be loaded in the same class loader?

Comment: You should call context.setClassLoader(classLoader) to make sure. Also classes you want to reload must not be available in classLoader's parent.

Comment: @mrembisz please put the above solution as an Answer. i will select that as the Answer. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can move some of your objects to a context which will be reloaded with a dedicated classloader. To make sure a proper classloader is used call `context.setClassLoader(classLoader)` before calling refresh or set thread classloader through `Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(classLoader)`. Also keep in mind if classes you want to reload will be available to some common parent classloader, they won't be reloaded since parent classloader always takes precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Would [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/) perhaps be a solution?

Comment: JRebel is a developer tool. I think, Vimal want to do this job in app.

Comment: @vacuum - Well, no it's not. It's a JVM plugin. Some people might only use it for development, but JRebel/LiveRebel enables hot code redeploy and zero-downtime deployments is a featured offering.